# fs.renameSync() throwing Error: ENOTDIR, not a directory but directory exists

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a script that uploads images and moves them to an './uploads' folder. This was working fine on my local machine, but just deployed the project to an EC2 instance for the first time tonight and am running into a really weird issue. When attempting to upload image(s), the server is returning the following error message:

```
Line of code that throws error: fs.renameSync(path, './uploads/' + newFilename);
Error: Error: ENOTDIR, not a directory '/tmp/6754-cp071e.jpg
```

I checked the /tmp directory, and an image named 6754-cp071e.jpg does in fact exist.  The permissions for both /tmp and /uploads have been set to 777 to ensure it's not a permissions issue. Any idea why this may be occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure what was wrong, but I read in another Stack Overflow post that node could throw the above error if the destination folder does not exist.  I removed ./uploads and remade it and for some reason it worked after that.  Maybe I had a typo in the folder name the first time around.